# Relating code from an ArrayList in a seperate method back to main method?

Tags: java

I appreciate this is most likely only an issue becuase of the poor construction of the code. However, when compiling, dictionary goes unrecognised in lines 11 & 12 because it is only declared in the second method. Is it possible to remedy this within the current draft or am I better to scrap this path and try another?

```
    import java.util.*;
    import java.io.*;
    public class ArrayListReader {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
    getDictionary();

    //Code for Scanners
    // Code for inputs
}
public static  ArrayList<String> name() throws Exception {
        //declare a String ArrayList object "filename"
      //Scanner object to read from fileName.txt

      // while loop to read from fileName.txt
      // Adds the next String to the  ArrayList
    return file;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to assign the result from `getDictionary` back to something, for example

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
    ArrayList<String> dictionary = getDictionary();
```

As a side note, you should also throw the actual `Exception`s coming from your methods, rather than just bundling them into the lowest common denominator.  Generally, this allows you to handle specific exceptions differently based on your needs

Comment: Thanks for the reply, so perfectly obvious when you say it. Is actually throwing the Exception in this case actually necessary? I was trying to avoid a try/catch.

Comment: @theLittleTrainThatCouldn't Thought it would throw an `IOException` and yes, it's a good idea to bubble the exception to the caller to make it's mind ;)

Answer (score 0):

`dictionary` is just a local variable defined in your `getDictionary` method, so it is not available in the main method.

You need to take the return from getDictionary method and assign to a variable, maybe like:

```
List<String> dictionary = getDictionary();
```